# Nginx, second WordPress site not loading, could the issue be with sites config file?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I am trying to install a second WP site (dancortes.press) on an Ubuntu 16 server running Nginx. The first site (microurb.club) has been successfully installed. I am not having a problem with that one.

I have successfully installed WordPress according to my server results for the second website (dancortes.press), but I still only get the Nginx home page. I thought it might be the fact that the Group Owner was the User, so I changed group owner on web files to www-data:

```
microurb@vps148370:/var/www/dancortes.press/public_html$ ls -l
total 192
-rw-r--r--  1 microurb www-data     0 Oct  5 15:36 index.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data   418 Oct  8 17:07 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data 19935 Oct  8 17:07 license.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  7413 Oct  8 17:07 readme.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  5447 Oct  8 17:07 wp-activate.php
drwxrwxr-x  9 microurb www-data  4096 Oct  8 17:07 wp-admin
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data   364 Oct  8 17:07 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  1627 Oct  8 17:07 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  2599 Oct  8 17:17 wp-config.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  2853 Oct  8 17:07 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwxr-x  5 microurb www-data  4096 Oct  8 17:19 wp-content
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  3286 Oct  8 17:07 wp-cron.php
drwxrwxr-x 18 microurb www-data 12288 Oct  8 17:07 wp-includes
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  2422 Oct  8 17:07 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  3301 Oct  8 17:07 wp-load.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data 34327 Oct  8 17:07 wp-login.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  8048 Oct  8 17:07 wp-mail.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data 16200 Oct  8 17:07 wp-settings.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data 29924 Oct  8 17:07 wp-signup.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  4513 Oct  8 17:07 wp-trackback.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 microurb www-data  3065 Oct  8 17:07 xmlrpc.php
```

I thought the problem may have been that index.html file and so I removed it and restarted nginx and still, I get only Nginx home page. I restarted Nginx a couple times.

I checked access and error logs and all I get is an error about code on the first site.

I checked the nginx access logs:

```
73.197.81.232 - - [08/Oct/2017:19:10:55 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
73.197.81.232 - - [08/Oct/2017:19:10:56 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

The error logs have an error regarding code on my first site:

```
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: success in /var/www/microurb.com/public_html/index.php on line 295" while reading upstream, client: 71.168.149.103, server: microurb.club, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "microurb.club"
2017/10/08 19:10:01 [alert] 22798#22798: *25 open socket #11 left in connection 3
2017/10/08 19:10:01 [alert] 22798#22798: aborting
2017/10/08 19:10:52 [alert] 23108#23108: *3 open socket #3 left in connection 3
2017/10/08 19:10:52 [alert] 23108#23108: aborting
```

I really do not know what to look for next. Why can I not see the WP site?

This is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/dancortes.press server file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/dancortes.press/public_html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;

        server_name dancortes.press;

        include global/restrictions.conf;
        include global/wordpress.conf;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

Below I am adding a screenshot of my DNS configuration:

[image]

Comment: I thnk the issue is that yo have your virtualhost file on sites-available, so you need to create a symlink to sites-enabled

Comment: @DiegoVelez, the symlink was created, but my second site was not configured for a 301 redirect like the first one, instead it was configured for CNAME www dancortes.press. In such a case, you do have to make the server_name www.dancortes.press, instead of just dancortes.press. Once I added the www to server_name, WP core site displayed just fine. No more Nginx welcome page.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages says the PHP in index.php is malformed on line 295. The Wordpress index.php is 17 lines long. It could be that the included files are counted as lines in that file.

Check what file the PHP interpreter is running. Reinstall Wordpress. Check your Nginxs settings that call PHP are correct. Some themes aren't compatible with PHP7.

Comment: Tim, the php error on line 295 is referring to the first website, which successfully loads in the browser. Are you suggesting that a coding error on the first site is affecting the ability of nginx loading the second site?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear there are two websites, perhaps calling them website1 and website2, saying which is working. Make sure any logs or configuration files are labeled with which website they're for.

Comment: I attempted to make it clearer by editing above, but the log files, I just did a less /var/log/nginx/error.log. I do not know how to ask it to just give me the error for the second site.

Comment: Tim, have no idea if you are still assisting but I just checked with info.php and PHP 7 is working, and its working through FPM/FastCGI from what I saw in Server API.

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information to solve the problem, at least not enough for me to help. Your question is also somewhat vague. You probably need to do more diagnostics yourself to work this out, or to hire a consultant.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have provided more information above. This should help you help me.

Comment: I think you need to hire a consultant for this. You don't seem to understand the problem well enough to give us the information we'd need to help solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot answer my own question because you blocked it as off-topic, which is not off topic. I have resolved this issue, but I cannot even properly close this. There is a reason why I posted the DNS console. The answer is right there.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to include the answer at the end. Interested to hear what it was.